# Unit Test kotlin for hibernate.sessionfactory.createQuery using mockk, what does this mean?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to mock out my calls to hibernate using the mockk framework.  I need to mock the Query object that is returned by here.  When I use the following code I get this compiler error, which not being a kotlin developer I don't understand.

> Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Query but Query<(raw)
> Any!>! was expected

```
        var mockedQuery = mockk<Query<Any>>{ }
        var mockSessionFactory = mockk<SessionFactory> {
        every { openSession() } returns mockk {
            every { get(any(), any()) } returns { null }
            every { createQuery("delete from SaveableObject where expiration < getdate() ") } returns { mockedQuery }
        }
```

How do I mock out that Query object?

Comment: Would it make a difference if you change the first line to `var mockedQuery = mockk<Query<Any>>()`? Looks like you have mockedQuery as a Provider for a Query, but not a mocked instance.

Comment: that results in a different error.  "Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Query<Any> but Query<(raw) Any!>! was expected"

Comment: Okay, maybe remove the braces after the `returns` inline function? It's not required as per the documentation and will lead to the wrong type (basically a Provider function for a Query, not a Query itself. So `returns mockedQuery` and maybe `returns null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
    var mockedQuery = mockk<Query<Any>>()
    var mockSessionFactory = mockk<SessionFactory> {
        every { openSession() } returns mockk {
            every { get(any(), any()) } returns null
            every { createQuery("delete from SaveableObject where expiration < getdate() ") } returns mockedQuery
        }
    }
```

I think the problem here is that you are using Supplier functions instead of the actual value.

A Supplier, as [in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), is a function with a signature `() -> T` and if you place a value in curly braces, you are assigning a Supplier, not the actual value.

Imagine

```kotlin
var helloWorld = { "Hello World" }
```

You cannot lowerCase it as `helloWorld.lowerCase()`, you need to call the function first `helloWorld().lowerCase()`.

In the same way, createQuery wants `Query<Any>` returned, not `() -> Query<Any>`

The other thing I changed is that I called `mockk()` for the query following one of the ways mentioned in [the documentation](https://mockk.io/#object-mocks) for object mocks which don't get any behavior injected.

Comment: This makes so MUCH SENSE!  I keep getting the meanings of { } mixed up between java and kotlin.